Passing a variable to msiexec in argumentlist doesn't work
So I've got this super simple script that uses msiexec to install a MSI, but it doesn't take the one of the flags.  This is the the format that installs correctly:
msiexec /qn /i "C:\temp\DNS_Agent_Setup.msi" NKEY="1234567890"

This script block fails because the NKEY likely isn't accepted:
param(
  [String]$SITESECRETKEY
  )
$key = "NKEY=`"$SITESECRETKEY`""
$msiPath = "C:\temp\DNS_Agent_Setup.msi"

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://download.dnsfilter.com/User_Agent/Windows/DNS_Agent_Setup.msi" -OutFile $msiPath
msiexec /qn /i $msiPath $key

Am I just dense?
When I replaced $key with NKEY="123457890" in:
msiexec /qn /i $msiPath $key
It works

Please format your post properly.

"NKEY=\"$SITESECRETKEY`""only works as anmsiexec.exeargument in _Windows PowerShell_ by default; if you're running PowerShell (Core) 7.3 or above, you'll need to (temporarily) set $PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing = 'Legacy'` -  see this answer for details.
